# Call exe file in web project using ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, exe

When I run 'test.exe' under web project using ActiveXObject, IE gave back the below error message -

> "The system cannot find the file specified."

Here is sample coding

```
function RunExe(){  
  w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");  
  var ex =w.Exec('test.exe');
  var ret = "";
  //read the output of the jar
  while (!ex.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) {
     ret += ex.StdOut.ReadLine();
 }   
 return true;
}
```

Here is project structure.

[image: Project Path]

Can you give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You request "text.exe", but the executable is named "test.exe".